# change date format to dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: javascript, jquery

the current date is showing in dd-mm-yyyy format but when i select the pop up showing in mm-dd-yyyy,after selecting also same thing

i want to change that to dd-mm-yyyy

```
const today = new Date();
    var journeyDate = new Date(),
        returnDate = new Date();

    journeyDate.setDate(today.getDate() );
    returnDate.setDate(today.getDate() );

    $(".journey-date").val(journeyDate.toLocaleDateString());
    $(".return-date").val(returnDate.toLocaleDateString());

    $(".journey-day-name").html(journeyDate.toLocaleString('en-us', { weekday: 'long' }));
    $(".return-day-name").html(returnDate.toLocaleString('en-us', { weekday: 'long' }));

    $(".journey-date").change(function () {
        var ojd = $(this).closest(".search-form-date").find(".journey-date").val();
        const journeyDayName = new Date(ojd).toLocaleString('en-us', { weekday: 'long' });
        $(this).closest(".search-form-date").find(".journey-day-name").html(journeyDayName);
    });

    $(".return-date").change(function () {
        var rd = $(this).closest(".search-form-date").find(".return-date").val();
        const returnDayName = new Date(rd).toLocaleString('en-us', { weekday: 'long' });
        $(this).closest(".search-form-date").find(".return-day-name").html(returnDayName);
    });
```

Comment: We are going to need more context to be able to help you.

Comment: Please add enough code to create a [mre]

Answer (score -1):

First ;
npm install moment --save

you can switch to any format;

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // February 12th 2024, 10:51:07 am
moment().format('dddd');                    // Monday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Feb 12th 24
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2024 escaped 2024
moment().format();                          // 2024-02-12T10:51:07+03:00
```

see the docs;  https://momentjs.com/

Comment: How does this address the issue?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).